# Solve the following diophantic equations

Tags: diophantine-equations, linear-diophantine-equations

I can't seem to find the solution to two problems in my textbook. 
They ask us to solve the diophantic equations: 1)

1. $xy²-2y²-x-6=0$
2. $4x²-4xy+y²-9=0$

I tried several things but these two just don't work out in my head. 
Even a step in the right direction would help.

Comment: For the second you can note that it is $(2x-y)^2 = 9$.

Comment: For the first one $y^2=\frac{x+6}{x-2}$, which means $x-2$ is a divisor of $x+6$.

Comment: i don't see how you have a form of ax²+bx+c=0 sure the -6 is c but but the other terms

Comment: 1. When does $(x-2)$ divide $(x+6)$? 2. 9 is a square.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite the first as: $x=\frac{2y^2+6}{y^2-1}=\frac{2(y^2-1)+8}{y^2-1}=2+\frac{8}{y^2-1}$.

Hence $y^2-1$ must equal $\pm1$, $\pm2$, $\pm4$ or $\pm8$. The only integer solution to this is $y^2-1=-1$ or $y^2-1=8$ giving $y=0,\pm3$ and hence $(x,y)=(-6,0),(3,-3),(3,3)$.

For the second one you can factorize it as: $(2x-y)^2=9$ and hence $2x-y=\pm3$ and hence $(x,y)=(t,\pm3+2t),\ t\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: I don't quite get how  you go from $2x-y = +- 3$ To the last part immediately

Comment: Rearrange it to $y=\pm3+2x$ then parameterize it by letting $x=t$.